# Preserve ordering in oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

I have a table called budget_statement which contains multiple rows with the same transaction_date where I am currently ordering by transaction_date

The problem is when I run the query in the database the ordering is different and when I run the query in BO report the ordering is different ie( row 15 is coming as row 17 in BO report where rows 15 to 17 have the same transaction_date)

Is there any way I can preserve the same ordering in the database as well as BO report without using any other column in the order by clause other than the transaction_date

Note:-I cannot use the rowid in order by because I am also using the order by in the below analytical function

```
 sum(credit) over (partition by user_ref_no order by transaction_date)
```

Edit1 #:-Also there is a primary key which is not there in resultset of the BO report  hence could not be used in order by

Comment: There is no natural order in the database table, it's an unordered set of data. If you have rows with the same transaction date then you need to specify a second expression in your order-by clause, to break those ties and return the rows in a consistent order. (I'm unclear why you can't use `rowid` if there are no other relevant column values... it would be consistent, though it has no real meaning for ordering.)

Comment: I am planning to use the second expression as rowid but problem is  the analytical function evaluates wrongly

Comment: I think I have to find a logical second expression other than rowid

Comment: I don't quite understand why the analytic result is wrong - but maybe you either need to include the `rowid` in *that* order-by clause too, so the sum in/decreases in the same order; or (depending on what you want to show) add a range clause so all rows on the same date show the same value.

Comment: ROWID is probably not a good choice; it **can be changed** so there's no guarantee that a certain row will have the same rowid tomorrow as it has today.

Comment: No, it's not ideal; but if there is nothing else, it's consistent in that the same query run from different clients against the same committed data should be in the same order, at least. Once data changes all bets are off though, I agree *8-)

Comment: How is the ordering in the BO result defined?

Comment: In the BO query I gave order by transaction_date,rowid but still it is only ordering by transaction_date not sure why

Comment: You should use: select user_ref_no, sum(credit) over (partition by user_ref_no order by transaction_date) from budget_statement order by rowid

Comment: Added the primary key in order by after transaction_date in analytical function as well as query resolved the issue

Comment: Your question said "without using any other column in the order by clause"... so was the issue really just with the analytic result and you didn't realise you'd need to add the same thing in *both* `order by` clauses, the overall query ordering and the analytic clause? If so what wasn't clear from your question (and mentioning rowid when you had a PK available was confusing). Explaining more and including sample data etc. would have been helpful.

Comment: The BO report doesn't have the primary key in the resultset hence thought of using rowid since i can use it without having it in resultset but not working.Now we have included primary key column in the resultset and asked the BO team to hide it in the report

Comment: You can order by a column or expression that isn't in the select list. You still seem to be making this harder than it needs to be.

Comment: The problem is whatever order by i give in the BO query it still order by only transaction_date only hence we had to resort to adding primary key to BO resultset and order by that, since I am novice in BO I don't know how to make BO report go by BO query order by